# Restar sumatoria acumulativa time(horas, minutos) con Codeigniter

Tags: php, date, codeigniter, datetime, horas

Es mi primer post, tengo un problema con los campos *time* con *Codeigniter*, cuando pasa las 24 horas me surge el error.

```
$sql = ("SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(horas))) AS total FROM tabla_ocho WHERE puesto = 'horarios' AND fecha BETWEEN '$desde' AND '$hasta'");
$query = $this->especificaciones->query($sql);

$horas = $query->getResult();
   
foreach ($horas as $reales) {
    echo $reales->total;
}
```

El resultado es 40:00:00 y es correcto, el problema es que soy nuevo en *Codeigniter* y no sé manipular el *time*, probé lo siguiente:

```
$muestra =  $reales->totales;
$horarios = Time::parse($muestra);
echo $horarios;
```

Y el resultado es:

> Exception
>
> Failed to parse time string (40:00:00) at position 0 (4): Unexpected character

Y con:

```
$muestra =  $reales->totales;
$horarios = Time::createFromTime($muestra);
echo $horarios;
```

> TypeError
>
> CodeIgniter\I18n\Time::createFromTime(): Argument #1 ($hour) must be of type ?int, string given

Y si uso *strotime* me da la hora errónea de 40:00:00

```
$muestra =  $reales->totales;
$horarios = date('H:i',strtotime($muestra));
echo $horarios;
```

El resultado del echo es "18:00"

El problema es que tengo restar, las sumatorias de horas de una tabla que son 40:00:00 a otra consulta de sumatoria que son 38:00:00, que es resultado sea 02:00:00

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Aunque suena a que puedes conseguirlo desde SQL,
si separas los componentes (hora, minuto y segundo) con `explode()`
puedes hacer la operación dentro de un `mktime()`:

```
$hms1 = explode( ':', '40:00:00' );
$hms2 = explode( ':', '38:00:00' );

$diff = mktime( $hms1[0]-$hms2[0]
              , $hms1[1]-$hms2[1]
              , $hms1[2]-$hms2[2]
              );

echo date( 'H:i:s', $diff ); // Resultado: 02:00:00
```

Comment: Sal lo probe y funciona perfecto, muchas gracias !